# Image.asset not appearing on a Android Emulator but working on connected device

Tags: flutter

I have a few .png in my `assets/icons/` folder, however when I to to use the image in my application it is not appearing. The element is using space like the image is there but I cannot see it.

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
      - assets/
```

**Code:**

```
child: Image.asset(
    'assets/icons/Tax-100.png',
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
    color: Colors.blue
),
```

**App:**

[image]

Edit:

I tried to run the application on my mobile device, and the img asset appears. why is it working on a connected device, but not emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Try listing your image explicitly in you pubspec.yaml file:

```
   assets:
   - assets/images/myfile.png
```

Not sure if it makes a difference but I keep pretty much all my images in assets/images.

Comment: It is the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

> only files located directly in the directory will be included; to add files located in subdirectories, create an entry per directory

As given [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

so it should be

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
      - assets/icons/
```